# Adding two layouts in a frame

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I'm a beginner in Android studio and I need some help. I have two buttons in a `FrameLayout` (button1 and button2) and a set of multiple buttons below. If button2 is clicked, the set of multiple buttons will change to another set and the other one were hide. How can I do that?

Comment: See Fragments https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html . Using them you can change a part of your screen.

Comment: Can I do listView to that and hide the listView(A) if I clicked the btn2 and show listView(B)?

Comment: If you want to use hide and show method, so you can insert two additional layouts in your parent layout below button1 and button2 and play with them using hide and show... But it is not a good practice.